# Copying a CCSprite? (cocos2d)

Tags: copy, properties, cocos2d-iphone, action, sprite

I'm trying to copy a CCSprite that's been subclassed. Let's say the file is called Names. And the original variable name is bob. If you wanted to copy all the actions of bob, how would you do that? By that I mean duplicating a CCSprite and have it have the same actions and attributes the original one has. I think I have to add the action as a property? How do you do that? I'd need to be able to copy "bob" many times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All actions are stored in the `CCActionManager`.  There isn't functionality right now to get all of the actions associated with an object but you could add a method to do so - look at `GetActionByTag` and `NumberOfRunningActionsInTarget`.

Once you get a list of the actions you can go through and copy them.  You'll want to write a copy function that for the sprite subclass as well as the actions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but who do you actually mass duplicate the ccsprite? ie - you make a sprite called bob with a spritesheet. how do you copy him 10 times?